# Rails Global Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my need: I have a table categories of a forum application. I need a variable that I can use in my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` so I can create a dropdown in the navbar with all categories in all the pages.

There's just one way I saw this as possible but as I am new to Rails I don't think it is the best, that is creating a `$categories = Category.all`. But as I said, it looks dangerous.

What would the best way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get data into `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`?

There's a controller just for that!

It's called `ApplicationController`.

In your `ApplicationController` do the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_categories

  # stuff..

  private

  def set_categories
    @categories = Category.all
  end
end
```

Now you have access to a `@categories` instance variable throughout your application code, including application layout.